# Get User Profile Information On Google Sign in Firebase and pass into New Activity

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, google-signin, android-bundle

How can I get the name and profile photo of a Google account from a FirebaseUser and show it in a new activity?
I have successfully integrated google login with firebase and authenticating but I am not sure how to show profile picture and username in a new activity I have read android Bundle documentation and passing the data in the bundle but I am still confused about how to do it in coding.

Auth Java  Code

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

User Details COde

```
// Initialize Firebase Auth
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseUser = mFirebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (mFirebaseUser == null) {
            // Not signed in, launch the Sign In activity
            startActivity(new Intent(this, PhoneAuthActivity.class));
            finish();
            return;
        } else {
            mUsername = mFirebaseUser.getDisplayName();
            if (mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
                mPhotoUrl = mFirebaseUser.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            }
        }

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
        mSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

[user details activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yR7AJ.jpg)

Comment: I am sorry I'm confused are you looking for how to pass data using bundle or "get the name and profile photo of a Google account from a FirebaseUser"?

Comment: @sanjeev Thanks for replying, I am trying to get the name and profile photo of the Google account from a FirebaseUser than I want them to show on different activity which is UserActivity in my project.